# BraintreePaymentActivity can not be found

Tags: braintree

I use Braintree as payment processor in a mobile app. In Android I use

```
import com.braintreepayments.api.dropin.BraintreePaymentActivity;
```

to import BraintreePaymentActivity

build.gradle has

```
compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:1.+'
```

It worked until today. Now, com.braintreepayments.api.dropin does not have this BraintreePaymentActivity anymore. What is going on?

Comment: [BraintreePaymentActivity](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_android/blob/master/Drop-In/src/main/java/com/braintreepayments/api/dropin/BraintreePaymentActivity.java) still exists in the Drop-In. Assuming you are using Android Studio, have you tried rebuilding and refreshing your project?

Comment: what is the version I should use?    I am using compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:1.0.0'

Comment: Try putting compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:1.+' in your build.gradle file. Here's the changelog for the [Braintree Android SDK](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_android/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) if you would like to pick a specific version to use with your app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add braintree project into your workspace.

1) download: http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/braintreepayments/api/braintree/1.2.7/braintree-1.2.7-project.zip

2) import into your workspace.

for more info: https://github.com/braintree/braintree_android/issues/18